# My timezone always back to China

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, time-zones

I have a Sony xperia c6 ultra.
I'm tring to set my timezone (and date/time) to automatic (via GPS and network).

I can change all this setting and can see the clock on top changing too. but when I left the config screen the time zone come back to China and the clock turn back again to the old time.

When setting all by hand and disabling all automatic settings, I can set the time/date and time zone but again, when left the config screen the time zone come back to China and the time/date still the one I set.

Having the date/time to my country and the time zone to China and disabling all automatic updates I can't use some app like Whatsapp.

Smell like a custom ROM joking me or a virus...
If it is not the original ROM can someone point me to instructions how to
put my phone back to original ?

**More info:**

```
Sony Xperia C6 Ultra
Android 6.0 
Kernel 3.4.5-526212
se.infra@SEI-44#1

Build number 23.0.1.A.5.77
Custom Build version
ALPS.L1.MP6.V2_GXQ6580.WEG.L_P69
```

Comment: There is no "Xperia C6 Ultra" (the closest matches are C5U and XAU), and the build number you posted doesn't match any released for those 2 devices (from what I dug up it's valid for Z3/Z3C only). Furthermore, the custom build version string points out that the device uses an MT6580 SoC, which no Sony device ever used. Combine this with the China timezone problem, and the authenticity of this device is questionable. You might want to contact the reseller.

Comment: Jesus. How can these people do such a thing?